# Next Pattern Puzzles

Tags: pattern

Fellas time for logical pattern test. I am practicing for some reason. I answered few of them. Some of them I couldn't solve so I need your help.

From option available, mark which diagram will come next in series.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

[View post in better quality on imgur.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obKuG.jpg)

Comment: I think the first one is E. The white rhombus goes from top to bottom and there is an arrow of the opposing color next to each rhombus.
The 8th one (bottom-right of the first page) is B. Notice how the first row shifts to the right by one each time and the second one shifts to the left twice each time.

Comment: I think so too.

Comment: i don't want to sound offensive, but as a designer of standardised iq test problems of the same kind, my personal opinion that some of these problems is at least ambiguous, or even poorly thought - for example some answers could be explained by having some periodicity in the elements, but a period of 3 (or even worse, 4) is just a bad choice, if only 5 pictures are given, as it does not allow to verify the reasoning on a large enough sample - referring to 4th page, 2nd row, left task. that being said, i will give them a try, and come up with answers for as many as i can. where are these from?

Comment: @elias I agree. For some of them the sample is too small and I only relied on the fact that the pattern for the answer was one of the choices in the answer.

Comment: 4×2 in Image 2, I am confused between B&E... :(

Comment: @HemantRupani If you're referring to image 2, row 4, right puzzle, the dots mean whether the pattern has moved up or down from what it was before. 2 black dots means it has moved up by 2, 3 white dots means it has moved down by 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I love these. For each image, I number the puzzles row by row from left to right, so that the first row has 1, 2, the second row 3, 4, etc.

Image 4 has the hardest puzzles by far, no suprise you didn't get any. Even some of my answers are a bit tenuous there.

I also disagree with your deduction in a few puzzles, which I've also mentioned. For the rest I assume we've both arrived to the same correct pattern and I consider them trivial to mention.

## Image 1

- puzzle 3

> **B**: The pattern is in groups of two. The first frame shows the initial position and the second the final position. The rule is that the circle stays where it is and the cross moves clockwise by one.

- puzzle 8 (I disagree)

> **D**: Each frame relates to the one 3 away, so frame 1 relates to frame 4, etc. Between such related frames, colour patterns are similar and white maps to black.

## Image 2

- puzzle 2

> **C**: The pattern is in groups of two. The second frame in each group shows the first one rotated by 45 degrees. Then, if the inner and outer circles have 2 black quadrants, they disappear, while for 1, it moves clockwise by one. For the middle circle take its complement.

- puzzle 4

> **D**: The pattern is in groups of three. The first frame shows object A surrounding object B. The second frame is two overlapping As surrounding object B and the third frame shows object B surrounding an overlap of 3 As.

- puzzle 5

> **D**: The cross moves towards the bottom right every two frames. The circle moves towards the top left every frame. If the circle is to coincide with the cross for a frame, it simply jumps over it and lands in the position it'd normally be two frames away. It also bounces when it reaches the boundaries.

- puzzle 7

> **C**: '/' moves horizontally to the left every 2 frames and wraps around after reaching the boundary. '\' moves vertically every frame and bounces back at the boundaries.

## Image 3

- puzzle 1

> **D**: Call the objects above the line from left to right A and B and the object below the line C. For the next frame, they all move anticlockwise by one, i.e., B becomes the new A and C becomes the new B. However, while A becomes the new C, it changes its shape and maybe its colour, too.

- puzzle 2

> **E**: The pattern is in groups of two. The sum of the dots of the top circles must be equal between the two frames. Ditto for the bottom circles.

- puzzle 3

> **C**: Call the objects from outer to inner A, B and C respectively. Initially, A encircles B, which encircles C, i.e., A(B(C)). Then, C becomes outer and the other two drop by a layer, i.e., C(A(B)). In the process, C may change shape.

## Image 4

- puzzle 1

> **B**: Tenuous. The frames relate with the one 3 apart, i.e, frame 1 related to 4, frame 2 relates to 5, etc. The arrow orientation stays the same, which is only matched by choice B. I can't figure out how the ball moves or when the arrows change colours to strengthen the pattern.

- puzzle 2

> **E**: The odd numbers relate sequentially, i.e, frame 1 relates to frame 3, frame 3 relates to 5, etc. Similarly, frame 2 relates to frame 4 and that relates to frame 6. The pattern is that the outer shape of the current frame becomes the inner of the next.

- puzzle 3

> **B**: The pattern is in groups of three. The shape goes from medium to large to small. The line(s) in the centre match orientations/rotation angle in each frame between groups.

- puzzle 4

> **C**: Tenuous. The shapes at the top rotate through square, circle, triangle, rhombus and at the bottom through triangle, rhombus, circle.

- puzzle 5

> **A**: In a clockwise direction starting from the top left, name the quadrants 1-4. Now imagine a horizontal line going through quadrants 1 and 2 in frame 1. This means that in the next frame these two will have rotated in some manner. The line in that next frame (2) will have rotated clockwise by 90 degrees, thus going through quadrants 2 and 3. More explicitly, in frame 1, line goes through quadrants 1 and 2. In frame 2, quadrants 1 and 2 have rotated and the line now goes through 2 and 3. In frame 3, quadrants 2 and 3 have rotated and the line now goes through 3 and 4. In the fifth frame, the line goes through quadrants 1 and 2, so we expect those to have rotated in our answer. The rotation is simple antisymmetry. Imagine a perpendicular line to our already imaginary line (axis). If one quadrant rotates by 90 degrees with respect to the axis, the other quadrant rotates by -90 degrees. Ditto for 180 and -180 degrees respectively.

- puzzle 6

> **E**: The black dot is in sync with the black oval. When the oval is at the top, the dot is at the bottom right. Rotate the pattern by 90 degrees to derive the other positions. A similar thing happens for the white oval and dot. When the oval is looking right, the dot is at the top right. So we can either focus on the dots or ovals for the complete pattern. The black dot moves anticlockwise by one and the white dot clockwise by one. There is a hiccup in frame 4 that I can't explain where black dot freezes and the white dot disappears. It can't overlap with the black dot, or else we'd see the white oval at the top. However, after that the dots resume the pattern of moving anticlockwise and clockwise.

- puzzle 7

> **B** (more inclined on this one), **D**, or **E**: Very tenuous. There are two different patterns to establish the ball should most likely be at the top right, but I have no clue about the line orientation.

- puzzle 8

> **C**: The black arrow points whether the dot next to it will move up or down in the next frame. The white arrow has no effect.

## Image 5

- puzzel 2 (I disagree)

> **E**: '\' moves to the right every frame and wraps around around at the boundary. '/' moves to the right every two frames and wraps around at the boundary.

- puzzle 5

> **A**: The pattern repeats the shape cirles, square, rhombus. Between frames, the black quadrant moves clockwise by one and the grey quadrant stays put. If the black quadrant overlaps with the grey, the grey will move out of the way. The grey quadrant can only occupy the top left or the bottom right and rotates between the two.

- puzzle 6 (I disagree)

> **D**: The odd frames have a pattern separately from the even frames, which have their own. For the odd frames the dot moves clockwise by half a line, while for the even frames the dot moves anticlockwise by half a line.

## Image 6

- puzzle 1

> **E**: The white rhombus goes down by one. When it reaches the bottom, it transposes to the right column and starts going down again from the top. The black rhombus does the same thing, except that it starts from the right column and transposes to the left. The arrows in the middle travel downwards by 1 and wrap around to the top if they reach the bottom.

- puzzle 2

> **C**: Each column of dots is independent. The left and right decrease by 1 and after hitting 0, they start increasing by 1. The middle column starts by increasing. However, when the column becomes full, instead of hitting number 5, it stays at 4 but the root switches from top to bottom. Then it starts decreasing. This probably applies to all columns, but we don't have enough evidence to safely extrapolate.

- puzzle 3 (I disagree)

> **B**: Each frame relates to one three away, i.e, frame 1 relates to frame 4, etc. The shapes remain the same but the colours are reversed.

- puzzle 4

> **E**: What matters is the number of objects in each line, i.e., 1, 2, 3 and 4. Let the rows from top to bottom be called A-D. Then, the mappings for the next frame are A->C, B->A, C->D and D->B. This has the effect of pairing 1 with 3 and 2 with 4. The pairs alternate between inner and outer. The outer pair switches its order when it becomes inner, e.g., 2xx4 becomes x42x, while the inner keeps the same, e.g., x31x becomes 3xx1. As another result, the pattern repeats every 4 frames.

- puzzle 8

> **D**: The first row moves to the right by one and wraps around. The second row moves to the left by two and wraps around. The third row moves to the right by two and wraps around. The forth row moves to the left by one and wraps around.

---

Furthermore, there are 4 puzzles you've answered that I haven't managed to settle down to a single answer. No reasonable pattern emerges early on and after grasping at straws, I come up with patterns that can arrive to multiple answers (even with only one pattern logic). For those I list my choices in order of preference. Looking at elias's answer, he seemed to have the same doubts as me (mostly).

Image 2, puzzle 6

> **B**/**A**

Image 3, puzzle 4

> **C**/**E**

Image 5, puzzle 4

> **C**/**E**/**B**

Image 6, puzzle 6

> **D**/**E**

Comment: great effort! for example, i love your approach on image2/puzzle5, for which i didn't really have a natural and well fitting idea!

Comment: Puzzle 8 of Image 1. In relation 2-5: grey remains grey. In my logic A is correct.

Comment: @HemantRupani You are correct! I still stick with my choice, only because white maps to black consistently. While choice A has a similar shape, I couldn't explain the colours.

Comment: @Reti43 Well! My logic is- after each step black will compress in 1 from 2 or expand in 2 from 1, BUT the expansion step done as anti-clockwise to where 2 whites/greys presents & center color change to white/grey respectively. And when the black compress grey and white interchanges color.

Comment: @k31453 Would it be possible to provide a link to the quiz so we can verify which answers are correct?

Comment: HI, I do not have answer to the link thats the problem. @Reti43

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in my comment before, the quality of these tasks is very mixed. Some of them are annoying, but there are really nice ideas as well - I think image 5, 2nd row, left is a great example that even a well thought problem is not enough in itself, if the possible answers are badly designed, a beautiful task can be answered with more simple reasoning than the one thought by the author. I mean

> "1 black thing on each chain - 2 black things on each chain" repeating

solves the problem just as well, as the probably intended solution, that

> shapes on left chain are progressing downwards, on the right one upwards, and colors of all of them alternate in each turn

1st image

> C; A
>  B; D
>  E; B
>  E; A (or maybe D?)

2nd image

> E; probably C
>  A; D
>  A? (@Reti43's idea of D fits more nicely); B (or A?)
>  C; B

3rd image

> D; E
>  C; C or E

4th image

> B?; E
>  E; B
>  A or C; could be anything but A
>  D? (or maybe B or E); C

5th image

> B; E
>  A; totally clueless on this one
>  A; D
>  C; C

6th image

> E; C
>  B; E
>  E; D
>  C; D

It's just too much to explain all of these, but if you have a specific question, please do not hesitate to ask!